# Angular mat-dialog opens twice

Tags: angular, mat-dialog

**Goal**:
I want a mat-dialog to show when the page is loaded.

**Problem**:
I noticed that the ngOnInit is triggered twice when I have a mat-dialog in there.

**What I've tried**:
I have tried moving it around to different methods but it seems to have no difference.
Ive also looked through some SO articles but not sure I am understanding the answer. I see some mentioning the change detection.

[Why is ngOnInit called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787795/why-is-ngoninit-called-twice)

[Angular Material Dialog is displaying twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588385/angular-material-dialog-is-displaying-twice)

**Typescript**:

```
ngOnInit()  
  {   
    
    sessionStorage.setItem('InActiveV', "false");

    // Start v in API and get  info    
    const staring = timer(500, 10000);
    this.startVSubscription = staring.subscribe(val =>{
      if (!this.isLoad) {
        this.PStartV();
      }
      else {
        this.startVSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
    this.cmdOpenDialog_click();
  }
  
  
  cmdOpenDialog_click() {
      this.dialog.open(DialogInternalNotesThreeComponent, {
          data: {
                data: this.internalNotes
            }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Try to move `this.cmdOpenDialog_click();` from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit` ?

Comment: @paranaaan I tried that just now, but it did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a fault in your dialog (or a fault in any child element in the parent element), for example a missing closing tag in the HTML, or something simple like that. In the past I've noticed that if there's a fault in a child element, the ngOnInit() of my parent element is sometimes called twice.

Comment: One interesting thing is that this dialog can also open if someone clicks a specific button on the page. When they click that button the dialog only opens once. But for the page load its opening two of them.